# Deep copy of tensor in tensorflow python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

In some of my code, I have created a neural network using tensorflow and have access to a tensor representing that network's output. I want to make a copy of this tensor so that even if I train the neural network more, I can access the original value of the tensor.

Following other answers and tensorflow documentation, I have tried the tf.identity() function, but it does not seem to be doing what I need. Some other links suggested the use of tf.tile(), but this did not help either. I do not wish to use sess.run(), evaluate the tensor, and store it elsewhere.

Here is a toy example that describes what I need to do:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

t1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
t2 = tf.layers.dense(t1, 1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
expected_out = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(expected_out - t2))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(t2, feed_dict={t1: np.array([1]).reshape(-1,1)}))
t3 = tf.identity(t2) # Need to make copy here
print(sess.run(t3, feed_dict={t1: np.array([1]).reshape(-1,1)}))

print("\nTraining \n")

for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={t1: np.array([1]).reshape(-1,1), expected_out: np.array([1]).reshape(-1,1)})

print(sess.run(t2, feed_dict={t1: np.array([1]).reshape(-1,1)}))
print(sess.run(t3, feed_dict={t1: np.array([1]).reshape(-1,1)}))
```

The result of the above code is that `t2` and `t3` have the same value.

```
[[1.5078927]]
[[1.5078927]]

Training

[[1.3262703]]
[[1.3262703]]
```

What I want is for `t3` to keep its value from being copied.

```
[[1.5078927]]
[[1.5078927]]

Training

[[1.3262703]]
[[1.5078927]]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named [`tf.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) operation and then run only that operation via [`Graph.get_operation_by_name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operation_by_name). This won't fetch the tensor's value but just run the assign operation on the graph. Consider the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(2,))
w = tf.Variable([1, 2])  # Updated in the training loop.
b = tf.Variable([0, 0])  # Backup; stores intermediate result.
t = tf.assign(w, tf.math.multiply(a, w))  # Update during training.
tf.assign(b, w, name='backup')

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    x = [2, 2]
    # Emulate training loop:
    for i in range(3):
        print('w = ', sess.run(t, feed_dict={a: x}))
    # Backup without retrieving the value (returns None).
    print('Backup now: ', end='')
    print(sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('backup')))
    # Train a bit more:
    for i in range(3):
        print('w = ', sess.run(t, feed_dict={a: x}))
    # Check the backed-up value:
    print('Backup: ', sess.run(b))  # Is [8, 16].
```

So for your example you could do:

```
t3 = tf.Variable([], validate_shape=False)
tf.assign(t3, t2, validate_shape=False, name='backup')
```

Comment: I don't think that this is quite going to work for my case. In your example, b is not dependent on a placeholder, so you can assign a specific value to it. In my above example, b (t3) should be dependent on the input to placeholder t1, so I cannot assign it a specific value.

Comment: Of course you will have to pass a value for `t1` to the `feed_dict` as well when you request the backup operation. But that's no different from how you attempted to do the copying before anyway: `sess.run(t3, feed_dict={t1: np.array([1]).reshape(-1,1)})`. Now you would do instead: `sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('backup'), feed_dict={t1: np.array([1]).reshape(-1,1)})`. Obviously you need to provide all dependencies since you can't backup something that has no value attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe copy.deepcopy() could work...
for example:

```
import copy 
tensor_2 = copy.deepcopy(tensor_1)
```

Python doc about deepcopy:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html